# Running blender from the command line

Tags: error

My blender will not run and it's been suggested that I run blender from the command line with a factory reset option however I am not familiar with how to do that.

What is the actual command after c:> ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll be describing two approaches, one for the case that you don't know where the `blender.exe` is located, there other for when you do.

In case you don't know Blender's install directory:

1. Open the Windows Explorer <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
2. Navigate to `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender` and verify that the `blender.exe` is present. If it is continue with step 4, otherwise step 3.
3. In case you didn't find the `blender.exe` go back to `C:\Program Files` and use the search box to search for `blender.exe`. When it's found right click on the item and select *Open File Location*.
4. Click in the address bar that displays the current path and replace the text with `cmd`. Press enter and a command prompt should open with the working directory set to the path where Blender is located.

---

If you already know Blender's install directory:

1. Open a command line <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd` and press enter
2. If Blender is on a drive that isn't `C:` you will have to change to the correct drive. You can do this by typing the drive letter and pressing enter. For example if Blender is located in `K:\05_Download\blender-2.80-windows64`, you would type `K:` and press enter.
3. Change the directory to where Blender is located. Use `cd` to change the directory, for example `cd K:\05_Download\blender-2.80-windows64`.

---

Now you can start Blender with the (temporary) factory settings. Once you close and restart Blender without the flag it will load your preferences. This is better than doing a factory reset, when you only need to temporarily disable preference loading.

```
.\blender.exe --factory-startup
```

Another flag that is useful in case Blender crashes is `--debug` which will display debug information on the command line.

```
.\blender.exe --debug
```

The full list of command line arguments can be found in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html).

Answer (score 0):

Running Blender from the command line is unlikely to make any difference. If Blender does not run correctly, check that your Graphics card supports OpenGL version 3.3 and [other minimal hardware requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) and that your graphics drivers are up to date. Also try [re-downloading Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/) and re-installing it. Also try the zipped version.

You do not need to run Blender to reset user preferences(factory reset), you can delete(maybe backup first) the user preferences files that are on `%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\[version number]`.

Comment: I tried and ran blender from the run/command box and it ran correctly but did not save the settings when I closed and re-ran the program.