# 3D axis are gone

Tags: interface, coordinates, axis, gizmo

The little 3D axis in the upper right corner were gone for months for me, I've tried everything with no results. I hoped that in version 4.0 it would be fixed but still nothing. I have all the gizmos enabled and everything. They don't appear in any view or mode. Has anyone had this problem before?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the gizmo? Or using **Ctrl + `**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top bar, go to *Edit > Preferences > Viewport* and in the *Display* section, set the drop-down menu *3D Viewport Axis* to `Interactive Navigation`. :-)

(There is also an option to show & hide the *Zoom*, *Pan* and *Camera* icons. Go to *Edit > Preferences > Interface* and in the *Editors* section, tick the *`[X]` Navigation Controls* checkbox.)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Blender but I would try to uninstalling the program and reinstalling. Could any add-ons be conflicting with program especially if they are out of date. The usual stuff like windows updates causing bugs and checking for viruses.

Another thought to check your drivers are up to date especially the graphics. They can sometimes fix random issues.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but note that the user preferences and any installed 3rd-party add-on installed by the user are stored in the user's home directory and they will "survive" a re-installation of Blender. Better start Blender with factory settings first (or rename the Blender settings directory). For Windows there is a factory settings start batch file. Alternatively, use the --factory-settings option (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/154603/107598) to start Blender temporary with factory settings.

Comment: Good to know as I was not aware of that. It might help me with my problem which I have been trying to solve myself.